# Difference between array.length and array[0].length in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays

When I create a new multi-dimensional array (in this case an array of objects)

```
public Block[][] block = new Block[50][70];
```

What is the difference between:

```
block.length
```

and

```
block[0].length
```

and then what is

```
block[1].length
```

Answer (score 7):

If you think of `Block[][]` as being rows and columns of `Block`, and each row being a `Block[]` of columns, and an array of rows would be a `Block[][]`, then:

```
block.length // the number of rows
block[0].length // the number of columns on row 0
block[1].length // the number of columns on row 1
// etc
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect? You have a **multi** dimensional array. Thus, there is more than one dimension. Each dimension has a length. With `block.length` you get the length of the first one (i.e. `50`), with `block[x].length`, you get the length of the second one (i.e., `70`).

Since you allocated your array like this, all `block[x].length` will be equal, no matter what you choose for `x`. However, you could have an array where the nested arrays have different lengths, then `block[0].length` might not be equal to `block[1].length`.

Comment: "Each dimension has a length" - not really, each *subarray* has a length, and they can be of different lengths. They're "jagged arrays".

Comment: @kviiri: That sentence was not about Java arrays in general but arrays when used as multi-dimensional arrays with `new X[y][z]`.

Comment: I'd still clarify that, as the question is specifically about Java arrays.

Answer (score 2):

here you have two dimensional array. it has 50 rows and 70 columns. it means...

about block array...
block array will look like (row & column wise)

```
block=   0...1...2...3...4...SO..ON...69
         1
         2           50
         3
         4
         5
         SO..ON
         ..
         ..
         49
```

Now you are having tabular format of block array. now lets say I want to get value of block[2][3]... it means 2th row and 3rd column which is 50 as shown above.

block.length   total rows of Block array.

block[0] is referring to 0th row of Block array and so block[0].length gives you columns associated with 0th row which 70 so ans would be 70 (Note:total count)....

and so on....

Answer (score 1):

`block.length` is the number of rows. `block[0].length` is the number of columns in row 0. `block[1].length` should have the same value as `block[0].length` since it has the same number of columns as the first row.